# Ускорение вывода из БД

Tags: python, django

У меня есть база пользователей и их больше 500,000 и я встроил их в Django и вывожу через админпанель
Проблема в том что он сильно лагает и тормозит
Как это можно исправить ?
Я пока не пробовал установить на сервер, а даже если установлю оно так и будет логать или нет ?

`admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import User, Admin_bot, Parse_user, BlackList, database_sqlite3


class Parser_user(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user_id', 'group_id', 'username', 'bio', 'first_name')
    list_filter = ('group_id', 'bio')


admin.site.register(Parse_user, Parser_user)
```

`models.py`

```
class Parse_user(models.Model):
    user_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='ID Telegram',unique=True,null=True)
    group_id = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, verbose_name='ID Группы',null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Username')
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Био')
    first_name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=250, verbose_name='Имя')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Базу'
        verbose_name_plural = 'База'
```

Comment: Какая конкретно страница лагает? Какие SQL-запросы при этом выполняются?

Comment: Страница вывода информации там есть PUT POST DELETE и GET запросы и оно очень долго грузит информацию с postgresql

Comment: Вот и смотрите, какой конкретно запрос долго грузит, почему долго, кто конкретно его запросил и зачем вообще он запрашивается

Comment: @andreymal GET запрос долго грузится запрашиваю его только я, я пока делаю это на своем компе через 8000 порт

Comment: Я говорю про SQL-запросы, а не про HTTP-запросы

Comment: @andreymal а как я его могу проверить ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140428/discussion-between-svatoydyavol-and-andreymal).

Comment: Ставьте [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/) и вперёд изучать

Comment: Хотя наличие `list_filter = ('group_id', 'bio')` подсказывает моему внутреннему телепату, что Django пытается вывести список из всех этих 500,000 элементов для отображения фильтра — и вполне логично, что это будет долго. Уберите эти фильтры, наверное?

Comment: что мешает оптимизировать запрос установить LIMIT - всё равно все 5000 строк на одну страницу выводить глупо, освойте пагинацию

Comment: @Shilgen в Django-админке по умолчанию 100 объектов на страницу

Comment: @andreymal да это помогло, спасибо